# C# merging two for loops, the second loop is the first upside down

Tags: c#, for-loop, merge

I have 2 for loops:

```
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i -= 2)
    {
          ....
    }

    for(int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
          ....
    }
```

which goes like, if `n = 7`, then `i` will get the values (in that order):

```
7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7
```

the code is the same is the for loops. It would be better if I could merge these two for loops. I'm new to C#. Any suggestions?

Edit: `n` is always odd

Comment: it really depends on what is happening in the loop bodies.

Comment: _"It would be better if I could merge these two for loops"_ - why, and what have you tried?

Comment: your loops are not equivalent, you end the first at 1 but start the second at 3...

Comment: You are asking us about your business logic? How should we know? If you merge them it's something different, so it really depends on your requirement.

Comment: Is n always will be odd (7, 9, 13 etc.)?

Comment: yes n is always odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will help, but here is one way to get that output using a single for loop:

```
var list = new List<int>() {1};
for(var i = 3; i <= n; i+=2)
{
    list.Insert(0, i);
    list.Add(i);
}
// if n is 7, list now contains 7,5,3,1,3,5,7.
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PXUVT60211)

Comment: Your live demo will not run, did you mean to do it like this http://rextester.com/UJW58096

Comment: @MattBeldon Yes, sorry. I've played with the names and forgot to change back. fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

It was quite fun to do so I will post my answer. Not sure it is better than just extracting the content of the loop in a seperate method.

```
using System.Linq;
var n = 18;
var odds = Enumerable.Range(1,n-1).Where(i=>i%2==1).ToList();
var reverseOdds = new List<int>(odds);
reverseOdds.Reverse();
var indexes = reverseOdds.Concat(odds.Skip(1));
and then your loop

foreach (var index in indexes)
{
...
}
```

Comment: It's better to avoir using ToList(), and new List<> for better performance (IEnumerable extensions should be enough)

Comment: I know this code is quite inefficient (it was not the intention to make it production ready). However, I did not find a linq way to code the reverse (which mutate the collection) other than an orderby which is much slower than doing the copy. If you have an hint, I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Why not *extract* the loops as a *method*? Especially if

> the code is the **same** is the for loops.

Something like this:

```
  private static IEnumerable<int> MyLoop(int n) {
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i -= 2)
      yield return i;

    // Let's support even n like 10
    for (int i = n % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 3; i <= n; i += 2)
      yield return i; 
  }
```

Then you can use it as a *loop*:

```
  n = 7;

  foreach (int i in MyLoop(7)) {
    ...
  }
```

And can *easily play* with the method:

```
  // Obtain an array: [8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
  int[] array = MyLoop(8).ToArray();

  // Join items and print them on the console
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", MyLoop(7)));
```

Outcome:

```
  7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 1):

"Simple" `for` loop:

```
int max = 7;
int min = 1;
bool up = false;

for (int i = max; i <= max; up |= (i == min), i = (up ? i + 2 : i - 2))
{
    ...
}
```

It's a shame you can't declare `up` inside the `for` loop definition itself...

Answer (score 1):

It's my solution:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = 7;
        Console.WriteLine("Sequence: " + string.Join(", ", genSequence(new List<int>(), N)));
    }

    private static List<int> genSequence(List<int> lst, int n)
    {
        lst.Add(n);
        if (n > 1)
            genSequence(lst, n - 2).Add(n);
        return lst;
    }
```

live demo here: http://rextester.com/QXNH15306